# unit testing in redux

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, redux

So the docs suggest using a mock store, but it's just recording all the actions and is not connected to any reducer. I basically just want to unit a test a component, and see that given an action has been dispatched, it changed- something like(in the most general way to describe):

expect(counter.props).to.equal(1)
dispatch(increment())
expect(counter.props).to.equal(2)

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple factors involved here.

First, even in normal rendering and usage, dispatching an action does not immediately update a component's props.  The wrapper components generated by `connect` are immediately notified after the action is dispatched, but the actual re-rendering of the wrapped component generally gets batched up and queued by React.  So, dispatching an action on one line will not be reflected in the props on the next line.

Second, ideally the "plain" component shouldn't actually know anything about Redux itself.  It just knows that it's getting some data as props, and when an event like a button click occurs, calls some function it was given as a prop.  So, testing the component should be independent from testing anything Redux-related.

If it helps, I have a whole bunch of articles on [React and Redux-related testing](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-redux-testing.md) as part of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).  Some of those articles might help give you some ideas.

Comment: Also, a lot of the tests in react-redux for `connect` are fine enough starting points for writing a test.

Comment: thanks, so what's the recommended approach?  I'm thinking about unit testing my components as dumb-redux-unaware-props-only and separately testing my state transitioning with reducers unit testing?